# How to get Android device Features using package manager

Tags: android, package-managers

I am developing an android application and I need android device features. I know that, by using package manager, `getSystemAvailableFeatures` method should be available. Still the method is not available Can any one help me by post some example or source code related to that.

Comment: What happened when you tried `getSystemAvailableFeatures()`??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use the following function to determine if a feature is available:

```
    public final static boolean isFeatureAvailable(Context context, String feature) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final FeatureInfo[] featuresList = packageManager.getSystemAvailableFeatures();
        for (FeatureInfo f : featuresList) {
            if (f.name != null && f.name.equals(feature)) {
                 return true;
            }
        }

       return false;
    }
```

The usage (i.e from Activity class):

```
    if (isFeatureAvailable(this, PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: How can i get the list of all features available for an android device ? The problem i m facing is that my app is not compatible when downloading it from the Google PlayStore. So I m unable to figure out which permission/feature is not allowing me to do the same.

Comment: @JatinJha  In order to **restrict app's visibility on Google Play** to devices that have certain features (e.g. _flash_, _camera_ etc.), you have to advertise that your application **depends on supporting a specific feature/features**, by putting a `<uses-feature>` tag in your manifest file.

Answer (score 14):

If you know the feature you want to check then you don't need to enumerate all system features and check against the one you're looking for. Since API level 5 you can use the PackageManager.hasSystemFeature() function to do the same job as the isFeatureAvailable() function shown in the previous answer.

For example...

```
PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();

if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC))
    Log.d("TEST", "NFC IS AVAILABLE\n");
else
    Log.d("TEST", "NFC IS *NOT* AVAILABLE\n");
```