# Device support removed warning coming when updating app on playstore Android

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play, apk

I have an existing app available on playstore which runs on min sdk 15. I had made some changes and try to update my app and when I uploaded my apk everything goes fine but before the publish on review section , playstore gives me a warning as below

> Device support removed Warning
>
> Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for
>   new installs on fewer types of devices.
>
> TipIf this is an unintended change, then retain this APK in the new
>   release or ensure that your new APKs support all currently supported
>   devices.

after seeing this warning i have search different forums to know what cause the problem

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644748/after-update-the-apk-supports-fewer-devices-than-previously)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644748/after-update-the-apk-supports-fewer-devices-than-previously)

most of my search indicate that if i have specify something in manifest like **android:required="false"** **screen support tags** etc

but the thing is i have not added any new library or hardware feature only added some new classes, i have no idea what makes the issue. i will show how my manifest and gradle looks for the existing app in playstore and my new update

My existing App gradle and manifest

**Gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {

    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
}

 //app gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 10
    versionName "2.0.0.3"
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(":volley")

compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.my.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />-->
<!--  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<!-- GCM Permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- LAUNCHER ACTIVITY -->

    <activity
        android:name=".LaunchActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name=".SliderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Sign In"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Login_Accent_Theme"
        ></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="Change Password?"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/App_Accent_Theme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/App_Accent_Theme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:label="Sign Up"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Login_Accent_Theme"></activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".YoutubePlayerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".VideoLessonActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".MTestActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MSummaryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".PdfActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>




    <activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FeedWebview"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="News Feed"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <!-- GCM CLASSES -->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.my.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <service
        android:name=".gcm.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".gcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

The above is my current app deatils on playstore

The following is the warning signed build from playstore

**gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {

    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

     //app gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 11
    versionName "2.0.0.4"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(":volley")


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

/*@new change gradle compile*/
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.my.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />-->
<!--  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<!-- GCM Permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- LAUNCHER ACTIVITY -->

    <activity
        android:name=".LaunchActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name=".SliderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Sign In"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Login_Accent_Theme"
        ></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="Change Password?"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/App_Accent_Theme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/App_Accent_Theme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:label="Sign Up"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Login_Accent_Theme"></activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".YoutubePlayerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".VideoLessonActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".MTestActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MSummaryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".PdfActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>




    <activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FeedWebview"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="News Feed"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <!-- GCM CLASSES -->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.my.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <service
        android:name=".gcm.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".gcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
   <activity android:name=".ui.FiltrActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoAction"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".ui.SolitActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoAction"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

I have only added 2 more activity on manifest and change the new butternife in gradle. can any one help me what cause the warning in playstore because I haven't made any major change in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099110/2615223) and the comments.
Most of the times it would be because of some manifest changes and some screen support or new permissions added and hence would be a good to go thing.