# Google Play doesn't show my application(with permission "CallPhone") for Tablet

Tags: android

how to show my application(with permission "CallPhone") in Google Play for Tablet does not have the option "CallPhone"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the permission CALL_PHONE but your application does not solely rely on using it (everything else works just fine without making use of the telephony features), you must also add this to your Manifest.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

**Source:** http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/02/25/xoom-permissions-android-market.html

That being said, you will also need to take care of the functionality. In every `Activity` that uses the `CALL_PHONE` permission, you must also check in your JAVA if the device supports it.

Example:

```
Context context;    // Some object, such as Activity, that extends Context
// ...
boolean hasTelephony = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
if (hasTelephony) {
    // DEVICE SUPPORTS CALL_PHONE. DO YOUR BIT HERE
}
else {
    // DEVICE DOESN'T SUPPORT THE CALL_PHONE FEATURE. SHOW A TOAST OR A DIALOG OR SOMETHING HERE
}
```

Comment: @ChaoukiAyachi: Glad to have helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:required="false"` for the uses-feature tag. The [Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) will help you.

Also see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299993/optional-permissions-so-an-app-can-show-on-all-devices-and-enable-optional-featu) as it answers the same question.