# Why does not android market support tablets for my application?

Tags: android, user-permissions, uses-feature

I published my android app on market, but it is not supported by tablets. My permissions are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

which uses-features as required false should i use for solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

It's because you have the `CALL_PHONE` permission.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14909282/833647).

As it states in that link you will also need to make sure you handle the possibility that devices do not have the telephony feature, if you don't already.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible of NFC or PHONE permissions

you should use `uses-feature`

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Read more about [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)