# How to add a new feature (Android Bluetooth LE) but also still build with minimum API?

Tags: android

I have added Bluetooth LE as a new feature on my app, however Bluetooth LE was added in API level 18, my app can work without LE support so I want my minimum API level to be set at 13, and then at runtime (or through a separate compilation process) want to check if the current device has a high enough API level to enable the LE functionality

Is there a process or a best design usage for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299993/optional-permissions-so-an-app-can-show-on-all-devices-and-enable-optional-featu

Comment: Great link, and def. helps with permissions, but for instance I have a class that needs to contain a 'BluetoothGatt' - something that is not going to be found in a previous API and won't work as part of my class privates