# The app is not compatible with Samsung GT-P3110 running on Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android, google-play

An application i have developed and have deployed on Google play is not compatible with Samsung GT-P3110 running on Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

From the Google search, i came to know it requires camera auto focus to be turned off as it's not supported by Samsung GT-P3110. I applied the patch but still the app is not compatible with the mentioned device.

Followings are the permissions and features the app is using:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Can some buddy suggest what else i would require to make the app compatible with the Samsung GT-P3110?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung GT-P3110 [appears to be a WiFi-only device](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/tablets/tablets/GT-P3110TSABTU). If so, it will not have telephony capability, and some of your permissions require telephony. You would need to add another `<uses-feature>` element saying that you do not require `android.hardware.telephony`.

Comment: For details, follow this link to another of Mark's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9300036/693752 and also this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/5264328/693752

Comment: I tried making telephony optional. But still the app is incompatible with the device.

Answer (score 0):

Like mr. Murphy said, if that device is WIFI-only device just add this into your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
```

and change the targetSdkVersion to 15

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

so your app will be conmpatible with your tablet.